# Passing string from php Captcha image script to another php script when cookies are switched off

Tags: php, session, cookies, captcha

I have a php captcha image script that passes back the captcha code using a session variable, but this won't work if cookies are switched off.

I want to try cover all eventualities, so my form will work even if cookies are switched off.

I was wondering if there was a way to pass $code back from captcha.php to contactus.php without using session variables.

I doubt it, but I thought I'd ask to see if I was missing anything.

**captcha.php**

```
session_start();

class CaptchaSecurityImages {

    var $font = 'monofont.ttf';

    function generateCode($characters) {
        /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
        $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters) { 
        $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }
    return $code;
}

function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
    $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
    /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
    $font_size = $height * 0.75;
    $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
    /* set the colours */
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
    $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
    /* generate random dots in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
    }
    /* generate random lines in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
    }
    /* create textbox and add text */
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
    $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
    $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
    /* output captcha image to browser */
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    $_SESSION['six_letters_code'] = $code;
}
}

$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 1 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6';

$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters);
```

**Contactus.php**

```
<img id="captchaimg" alt="captchaimg" src="<?php echo htmlentities(getSiteURL() . '/server/includes/captcha.php'); ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about managing session without having a cookie support, read this article of [how to handle session without using cookie](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/Session_Management_Without_Cookies.html)